# C# in VS2005: determining what type an Object really is

Tags: c#, oop

In C# using VS2005, if I have a variable of type `Object`, to which I assign a `MyObjectType` object by casting as follows:

```
MyObjectType myObj = GetMyObject();
Object obj = (Object)myObj;
```

Is there way to determine that `obj` is actually a `MyObjectType` and not just an `Object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
if (obj is MyObjectType)
{
    ...
}
```

Or, if you want to then use some members of it:

```
MyObjectType mot = obj as MyObjectType;
if (mot != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that these will work even if `obj` refers to an object *derived* from `MyObjectType`. If you only want an exact match, you should use:

```
if (obj != null && obj.GetType() == typeof(MyObjectType))
```

... but that's a pretty rare use case in my experience.

Comment: @John: but isn't obj an Object and not an MyObjectType?

Comment: @Craig: No, you assigned a `MyObjectType` to it, so it’s a `MyObjectType`, even if it’s stored in a variable of type `object`.

Comment: @Craig: `obj` is a variable, not an object at all. The *value* of `obj` isn't an object either - it's a reference. It may be a reference to an instance of `Object`, or to an instance of `MyObjectType`, or some other type... or null. Note that the type of an object itself never changes, even if you store a reference to it in a different type of variable.

Comment: @John: if I want to use some members of it, can I cast and then refer to a member all in the one line?

Comment: @Craig: You can cast and then use the result directly, but it will throw an exception if the object isn't of the right type. You'd write `((MyObjectType)obj).SomeMember()`

Comment: @Jon: is the (obj is MyObjectType) style of expression an acceptable way to perform some programming logic within a program? Or is there a danger that something could go wrong? Does this have anything to do with Reflection?

Comment: @Craig: Usually you *do* want to use the object afterwards, so the second form is simpler. I'm not sure what kind of "danger" you're thinking about. It doesn't really have anything to do with reflection, as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if obj is a MuObjectType you can write

```
if( obj is MyObjectType)
```

This returns `true` if obj is infact a MyObjectType, else `false`.